# Undefined \section in RevTeX 4-2

Tags: revtex

I am typesetting a paper in the RevTeX 4-2 class and I am trying to add in sections. I put in PRA as the journal type, but for some reason TeXstudio throws in ``undefined control sequence \section{Introduction}", which does not seem to be a problem in Overleaf. The code is as follows:

```
\documentclass[
reprint,
aps,
pra,
%prb,
%rmp,
%prstab,
%prstper,
%floatfix,
]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mathdots}
\usepackage{yhmath}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{extarrows}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{bm}% bold math
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}
    
    \preprint{APS/123-QED}
    
    \title{Black holes stuff}%
    
    
    %No dates, please.
    %\date{\today}% It is always \today, today,
    %  but any date may be explicitly specified
    
    \begin{abstract}
        Blah blah blah.
    \end{abstract}
    
    %\keywords{Suggested keywords}%Use showkeys class option if keyword
    %display desired
    \maketitle
    
    \section[Introduction]{Introduction}
    
    
    \bibliography{apssamp}%
    
\end{document}
%
% ****** End of file apssamp.tex ******
```

What seems to be the problem with this? I tried to change journal types but I don't think that did anything.

Comment: Welcome! Your code compiles with no errors here (although you are loading packages several times, and you have warnings you should consider). I have an up-to-date TeXLive 2023 installation, so probably it's a problem in your setup/installation.

Comment: @Rmano Yeah I realized I have some redundant reloading of packages -- I had to copy paste a template a colleague sent and add some commands so I didn't check properly. I see, I will have to retry this I guess. Thank you very much for the timely reply!

Comment: Try getting rid of as many packages as possible while still reproducing the error, and then paste the whole `.log` file into the question.

Comment: texstudio is notorious for making tex error messages meaningless, ignore the useless message summary and look in the log file where the message will show which command is undefined (it will not be `\section`)

Comment: I'm voting to close as needs details, this is a works for me and should generally work, please edit the question to add the full log file, ideally with as few packages loaded as necessary to reproduce the error.

Comment: A helpful strategy is to comment out all packages, compile, remove comments of packages (i.e. activating them again) compile by compile until everything is fine.If I‘m not wrong your file will compile already after removing all packages shown. Then work from there.